# How do I solve the problem of "name 'score' is not defined" when running my nlp script using python?

Tags: python, nlp, undefined

When running my script, I got the following feedbacks,

> 1 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "testcore.py", line 20, in
>   
>       print(f'\tScore: {score[0]}, Value: {score[1]}')
>   NameError: name 'score' is not defined

The exact same script can run perfectly on another computer, I just don't get what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```py
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
fhand=open('airbnbuk.txt', encoding='utf-8')

count=0
for sentence in fhand:
    print(sentence)
    count=count+1
    print(count)
    result = nlp.annotate(sentence,
                               properties={
                                'annotators': 'sentiment',
                                'outputFormat': 'json',
                                'timeout': '5000'
                               })
    for s in result['sentences']:
        score = (s['sentimentValue'], s['sentiment'])
    print(f'\tScore: {score[0]}, Value: {score[1]}')
nlp.close()
```

Comment: Looks like that `print` is supposed to be in the `for` loop. `score` may not exist outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, it did work after putting print in the for loop. But I just don't get why it says 'score is not defined'. It should still exist as the last value passed into 'score', right?

Comment: If `result['sentences']` is `None` or empty, you never enter the loop and score is never defined. Remember, loops are like an if statement in this way because there is no guarantee that the code inside will ever be run. I'm curious whether `result['sentences']` is actually `None`/empty or if the interpreter is just throwing the error given the possibility that score does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

<s>Must be a `python` version mismatch. The format string was introduced in `Python 3.6`. You could be running a lower version where you get the error.</s>

### EDITED

OK, it's nicer to see the edited/formatted question.
So the reason for this is the for loop scope. You define `score` inside of the for loop and try to access it outside of the for loop scope.

If you change your code to either include a default value for score, or check if score exists, your code will work:

```py
for sentence in fhand:
    ...

    score = None
    for s in result['sentences']:
        score = (s['sentimentValue'], s['sentiment'])
    if score is not None:
        print(f'\tScore: {score[0]}, Value: {score[1]}')
```

or

```py
for sentence in fhand:
    ...

    score = (0, 0)  # some default tuple
    for s in result['sentences']:
        score = (s['sentimentValue'], s['sentiment'])
    print(f'\tScore: {score[0]}, Value: {score[1]}')
```

Comment: already updated to the latest version Python 3.7.4. The same problem still happens.